# PHP mongo - projection on particular array value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following query:

```
$aggregate = [
        ['$unwind' => '$positions'],
        ['$match' => ['positions.banner_params.project_location_id' => (int)$projectId]],
        [
            '$project' => [
                'page_id' => '$_id',
                'position_id' => '$positions.id',
                'page' => [
                    'website_id' => '$website_id',
                    'rate_tic' => '$rate_tic',
                ],
                'banner_params' => [
                    'title' =>  '$positions.banner_params.title',
                    'tmpl_id' =>  '$positions.banner_params.tmpl_id'
                ],
                'tmpl' => '$positions.tmpls',
                '_id' => 0
            ]
        ],
    ];
    $rows = $collection->aggregate($aggregate);
```

It returns such result:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [page_id] => MongoId Object
            (
                [$id] => 5527a3a276098d86ae9aa3aa
            )

        [position_id] => 1
        [page] => Array
            (
                [website_id] => 41
                [rate_tic] => 10
            )

        [banner_params] => Array
            (
                [title] => My Title
                [tmpl_id] => 2
            )

        [tmpl] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [width] => 500
                        [height] => 100
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [width] => 160
                        [height] => 400
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 7
                        [width] => 384
                        [height] => 115
                    )

            )

    )
```

How do I get into the tmpl only the template that match the banner_params.tmpl_id?

Comment: Show us an input document.

Answer (score 0):

first let me sure if i understand it correctly. you want to filter items in the `[tmpl] => Array` by `[id]`.

you cannot do that directly as the [tmpl] is an embedded object however as the aggregate is a pipeline function you can convert the current output the way you can filter and with `$unwind` then filter it again with `$match` and finally get the document as you wanted with `$group`. Something like below code should achieve what you want;

```
    $aggregate = [
        ['$unwind' => '$positions'],
        ['$match' => ['positions.banner_params.project_location_id' => (int)$projectId]],
        [
            '$project' => [
                'page_id' => '$_id',
                'position_id' => '$positions.id',
                'page' => [
                    'website_id' => '$website_id',
                    'rate_tic' => '$rate_tic',
                ],
                'banner_params' => [
                    'title' =>  '$positions.banner_params.title',
                    'tmpl_id' =>  '$positions.banner_params.tmpl_id'
                ],
                'tmpl' => '$positions.tmpls',
                '_id' => 0
            ]
        ],
        ['$unwind' => '$tmpl'], // makes every item as a colection
        ['$match' => ['tmpl.id' => (int)$your id]], //filter the records
        ['$group' => ['_id' => '$page_id', tmpl:{$push:"$tmpl"} ]] // rebuild collection as you wanted you can use a compound _id if this is not enough
        //if you don t want to see _id apply another projections to change it.
    ];
    $rows = $collection->aggregate($aggregate);
```

Might have some errors but this is the logic you should implement.

EDIT:

There is also `$redact` [DOC](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) to remove items in sub documents please see the example.

> Restricts the contents of the documents based on information stored in
>   the documents themselves.

Comment: Yes, I also tried your approach but I have a problem with second match:
If I write it directly it works:
['$match' => ['tmpl.id' => 2]]  
But this way not works:  
['$match' => ['tmpl.id' => '$banner_params.tmpl_id']  
or   
['$match' => ['tmpl.id' => '$positions.banner_params.tmpl_id']

Comment: I have never accessed a parent property but it looks like it is simple typo or there is another key word for that. try $eq:['$key', '$key2'] format

Comment: Double checked, there are no typos. Actually, I don't understand how should I use $eq with $match.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to  [Onur TOPAL's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/604876/onur-topal) advice I found the solution. One more $unvind followed by $redact did the job.

```
$aggregate = [
    ['$unwind' => '$positions'],
    ['$match' => ['positions.banner_params.project_location_id' => (int)$projectId]],
    [
        '$project' => [
            'page_id' => '$_id',
            'position_id' => '$positions.id',
            'page' => [
                'website_id' => '$website_id',
                'rate_tic' => '$rate_tic',
            ],
            'banner_params' => [
                'title' =>  '$positions.banner_params.title',
                'tmpl_id' =>  '$positions.banner_params.tmpl_id'
            ],
            'tmpl' => '$positions.tmpls',
            '_id' => 0
        ]
    ],
    ['$unwind' => '$tmpl'],
    [
        '$redact' => [
            '$cond' => [
                'if' => ['$eq' => ['$tmpl.id', '$banner_params.tmpl_id']],
                'then' => '$$KEEP',
                'else' => '$$PRUNE'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```